# Android skipping the splash screen when re-opening the app after having pressed back

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

So my scenario is as such.
Let's say there is a `MainActivity`, which only job is to start, call `installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }` to show the Splash screen using the new backward compatible APIs, and then after checking some state it does `startActivity(SomeActivity); finish()`

Now we're on the `SomeActivity` and if we press the home button, the app is gone on the background. Then if we click on the launched icon, the `SomeActivity` is launched correctly, and the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` is never called, therefore the splash screen does not show again, and the `SomeActivity` shows instantly.

But if instead of pressing the home button, we press the back button, and the app is backgrounded that way, then when we click on the launcher icon, the `MainActivity`'s `oncreate` is called again, and the splash screen icon flashes for a tiny fraction too making it look jarring.

My question is, does this sound like it's some wrong configuration on my part, or am I stuck with this behavior as long as I am not on a single activity architecture?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no solution to what I am facing as long as the Activity I want to resume to is not the Launcher activity.

From the [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#back-press-behavior):
"Root launcher activities are activities that declare an Intent filter with both ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. These activities are unique because they act as entry points into your app from the app launcher and are used to start a task.

System behavior on Android 12 and higher
The system moves the activity and its task to the background instead of finishing the activity. This behavior matches the default system behavior when navigating out of an app using the Home button or gesture."

Reading the docs about the new back behavior on Android 12 and onwards tells us that pressing back when you got nothing else on the stack will act as if you pressed the home button.
There's a big exception here, and that is that when you re-open the application, if the one you just popped was not the launcher activity, it will then still need to launch that launcher activity and can't resume from where you left off in a hot state, exactly the reason why I am seeing the splash screen again.

So I think my best bet is to either ignore this for now, or fix my app to be a single-activity app, or at least keep the launcher activity be the top-level one that you exit the app from by pressing back

To indicate a couple of examples, if one wants to experience what I mean, the reproduction steps are to:

1. Open the app
2. Press the back button which will send you out of the app to the home screen
3. Click on the app icon again

As of today, apps like Google Photos, and Google Podcasts don't show the splash again. In contrast, apps like Google Maps, Twitter, Spotify do show the splash again for a brief second.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused. Pressing the BACK button does not "send the app to the background". The default behaviour of the BACK button (assuming that you don't override this and provide your own behaviour) is to finish the current `Activity`. Normally this will take the user to the previous `Activity` in the current task. In your case, there is no other `Activity` in the task stack, so the current task is empty. This may appear to the user as "the app is sent to the background", but in reality there is nothing in the background. Your app's task is empty and so it is gone.

When the user then taps the app icon on the HOME screen or taps on the app's task in the list of recent tasks, there is no existing task to bring to the foreground, so the app is started again by creating a new task and launching the root `Activity` (in your case `MainActivity`) into the newly created task.

If you want the BACK button to just put your app into the background (instead of calling `finish()` on `SomeActivity`, which is the default behaviour) then just override `onBackPressed()` in `SomeActivity` and do this instead:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: No I don't think I am confused regarding this. What you are saying true all the way to Android 11. From Android 12 and on what you are saying is wrong, which is exactly what I mention in my other answer. Read more about this here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#back-press and especially the "Note" part which explains what I mention in my other answer. Specifically "The system applies the new behavior only to launcher activities that are the root of their tasks—that is, to activities that declare an Intent filter with both ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_LAUNCHER."

Comment: Yes, the new behaviour in Android 12 would background a task instead of finishing the `Activity` if there was only 1 `Activity` in the task and that `Activity` is the launch `Activity` for the app. But I've given you a way to simulate this in your architecture using `moveTaskToBack()`.

Comment: But this only helps on Android 12 and higher. Users of older Android versions would still have the problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is what I was trying to understand in my case. I didn't know how to at the time of writing the question, but I did figure it out as shown in my answer where I say "... or at least keep the launcher activity be the top-level one that you exit the app from by pressing back".
I do understand that this is only available as a fix for Android 12 and on, but that's okay, in older versions they will simply see the splash screen again. Thanks for giving your input!

Comment: Oh and `onBackPressed` is deprecated since API 33, so it may be a good idea to stop suggesting it going forward just in general.

Comment: I don't understand. If you use the solution I suggested, it also works with older versions of Android. They won't see the splash screen again. This is a perfect solution to your problem for both older and newer Android versions.

Comment: Yes, but I was not looking to alter the default Android implementation. Only to not break the new functionality that 12 provides.

Answer (score -1):

to call the launcher activity every time you have to clear the stack that means you have to use a flag in your manifest to tell your app not to keep activity in background try `android:launchMode="singleTask"` inside your `activity` tag in manifest the activity that you want to be killed everytime you go to background, and as far as how much time splash should be showing you can use timer for that after the timer is finished then your someActivity will be called.

Comment: No I think you've misunderstood my question.
I don't *want* to call the launcher activity when opening the app again after it was closed by clicking back. On the contrary, I'd like it to open the activity in which I was currently at before, just like it functions when exiting the app by clicking the home button instead of the back button.
Same for the second part of your answer, I don't want to artificially make the splash screen show for more than it needs to, on the contrary again, I don't want it to show at all when opening the app again, just like Google's "Photos" app acts for example.

Comment: ok in that case you can call the home launcher on the back press by overiding  `onBackPress`

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above:
"Yes, but I was not looking to alter the default Android implementation. Only to not break the new functionality that 12 provides."
Also a side note, as I said in another comment as well:
"... onBackPressed is deprecated since API 33, so it may be a good idea to stop suggesting it going forward just in general."